# After selecting to sort on column header, screen displays first value in report

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex, oracle-apex-5

When sorting on a column in an interactive report, whether it be ascending or descending, after selection, the screen refreshes and displays just the first cell's value in the interactive report on an otherwise blank screen.

[image: After Sort]

Has anybody else had this problem?

Is there a way to specify the default sort?  APEX is currently sorting in descending order when page is initially displayed.

Gif showing the problem...once I select to sort the columns, screen displays the value of the the first field in the interactive report.  After I select the browser back button, report is displayed again, columns sorted correctly.

[image: Sort Columns Problem GIF]

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Welcome to Stackoverflow.com! Please make your question a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example [MVCE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Also check [how to ask question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to make your post answerable.

Comment: Which Apex version is it?

Comment: APEX version 5.0, and I've also added a gif showing the issue.

Comment: You can specify the "default sort" in your IR SQL query:

`select * from customers order by last_name, first_name`

Answer (score 0):

If there's something that works out of the box is sorting columns on Interactive Report/Grids.

Please consider using this https://www.cockos.com/licecap/ to make a gif or even replicate your problem on apex.oracle.com, so then everybody could help you better.

Comment: Thanks for the tip on LiceCap!  I've added a gif showing the issue.  I agree, if there's something that should work OOB, it's column sorting, but somewhere along the way, it got screwed up.  Let me know if you have any ideas.  Thx!